# PHP upload de arquivos pra múltiplos diretórios

Tags: php, html, multiple-file-upload

Opa, tudo certo?! Tenho o código abaixo pra fazer o upload de arquivos pra vários diretórios com anos/meses:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="Backup!" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $year= Date('Y');
    $month = Date('m');

$tempFile = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
    for ($a=2017; $a <= $year; $a++) {
        echo "primeiro<br>";
        if($a == 2017){
            for ($m=11; $m <= 12; $m++) {
                $targetDir = "../".$a."/".$m."/";
                echo "segundo<br>";

                foreach ($tempFile as $key => $tmp_name) {
                    echo "terceiro<br>";

                    $fileName = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
                    $fileTemp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
                    $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;
                    echo $targetFile."<br>";

                    if(!file_exists($targetFile)){
                        if(move_uploaded_file($fileTemp, $targetFile)){
                            echo "uploaded!<br>";
                        }else {
                            echo "error<br>";
                        }
                    }else {
                        echo "file already exists in ".$targetDir."<br>";
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

2017 tem somente dois diretórios (11 e 12). O upload acontece certinho pro mês 11 mas entre no `echo erro` quando chega no diretório do mês 12.

A sequencia do looping que tá fazendo é essa:

```
primeiro
segundo
terceiro
../2017/11/file-to-change.php
uploaded!
segundo
terceiro
../2017/12/file-to-change.php
erro
primeiro
primeiro
```

Eu tentei usar um outro `for()`ao invés de `foreach()`mas dava a mesma coisa. Eu consigo fazer o upload pro primeiro diretório mas na hora que vai pro segundo não dá certo. Poderiam me ajudar? Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive que pensar de outra forma. Me corrijam se eu estiver errado mas acredito que no segundo looping acabava perdendo a fonte do arquivo já que ele tinha sido gravado/movido  no primeiro diretório escolhido e na hora do segundo o arquivo já não estava mais disponível.

Então, faço o upload para o primeiro diretório e após isso faço cópias desse cara para os outros diretórios:

```
foreach ($tempFile as $key => $tmp_name) {

    $fileName = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $fileTemp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;

    if(!file_exists($targetFile)){
        if(move_uploaded_file($fileTemp, $targetFile)){
            echo "Upload feito em: ".json_encode($targetDir, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)."<br>";
        }else {
            echo "Erro de upload em: ".json_encode($targetDir, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)."<br>";
        }
    }else {
        echo "Arquivo já existe na pasta ".json_encode($targetDir, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)."<br>";
    }
}

for ($a=2017; $a <= $ano; $a++) {
    if($a == 2017){
        for ($m = 11; $m <= 12; $m++) {
            $targetDirToCopy = "../".$a."/".$m."/".$fileName;
            if(copy($targetFile, $targetDirToCopy)){
                echo "Copiado para: ".json_encode($targetDirToCopy, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)."<br>";
            }else {
                echo "Arquivo já existe na pasta ".json_encode($targetDirToCopy, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)."<br>";
            }

        }
    }
    if($a == 2018){
        for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) {
            $targetDirToCopy = "../".$a."/".$m."/".$fileName;
            if(copy($targetFile, $targetDirToCopy)){
                echo "Copiado para: em".json_encode($targetDirToCopy, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)."<br>";
            }else {
                echo "Arquivo já existe na pasta ".json_encode($targetDirToCopy, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)."<br>";
            }

        }
    }
    if($a == $ano){
        for ($m = 1; $m < ($mes-1); $m++) {
            $targetDirToCopy = "../".$a."/".$m."/".$fileName;
            if(copy($targetFile, $targetDirToCopy)){
                echo "Copiado para: em".json_encode($targetDirToCopy, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)."<br>";
            }else {
                echo "Arquivo já existe na pasta ".json_encode($targetDirToCopy, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)."<br>";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o problema está neste seguinte trecho:

```
for ($m=11; $m <= 12; $m++) {
            $targetDir = "../".$a."/".$m."/";
            echo "segundo<br>";
```

Esse erro já aconteceu várias vezes comigo quando precisei fazer comandos de repetição. tente fazer assim:

```
for ($m=11; $m < 12; $m++) {
            $targetDir = "../".$a."/".$m."/";
            echo "segundo<br>";
```

Sei que é meio tosco, mas comigo sempre funcionou

Comment: Pior que já tentei. Mas aí ele não pega o mês/diretório 12.